# Flatpickr creates additional input field

Tags: laravel, flatpickr

I'm implementing a project in laravel. There is a view with some input fields. One of them should be viewed with flatpickr. Although default options are used, flatpickr adds always an additional input field. I want to use my defined input field with flatpickr.

Generated code:
[image]

I tried already to override the default option with altInput: false but this doesn't work at all.

```html
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <h3>Buchung {{ isset($booking) ? 'ändern' : 'anlegen' }}</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <form method="post" action="{{ isset($booking) ? route('bookings.update', $booking->id) : route('bookings.store') }}">
        @csrf
        @if (isset($booking))
          @method('PUT')
        @endif
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="project">Projekt</label>
          <select name="project" class="form-control">
            @foreach ($projects as $project)
              <option value="{{ $project->id }}">{{ $project->name }}</option>
            @endforeach
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-3">
            <label for="date">Datum</label>
            <input type="text" id="date" name="date" class="form-control">
          </div>
...

@endsection

@section('scripts')
<script>
flatpickr('#date');
</script>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, flatpickr was creating a new input field - hidden, it did not create a new input field visible in the browser - because *altInput:* was set to *true*. I am not sure if you can set it to *false* without compromising what you want to achieve, but maybe this leads you in the right direction to fix it?